# CANOT POST /php - Integración NodeJS con PHP

Tags: php, javascript, nodejs, postgresql, soap

Amigos necesito su ayuda. Necesito realizar una consolidación (sacar las diferencias) de los datos obtenidos por un WebService SOAP y compararlos con datos ya existentes en una BDD en Postgres. 
Estoy utilizando NodeJS porque luego de obtener ciertos resultados, debo ejecutar un CRON que actualizara otra BDD.
Mi código HTML está así:

```
<!-- TAB 1 -->
        <div class="row justify-content-center text-center align-items-center" id="tab_1">
            <div class="row">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="consulta_cat" value="consulta_cat">Consultar
                    Categorias SoftExpert</button>
            </div>

            <div class="row">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>

            <div class="col-5 pt-5">
                <table class="table" id="tbodyT">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>CATEGORIA</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="siguiente_tab1" value="siguiente_tab1">
                    Siguiente</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

En donde tengo un boton con el id="consulta_cat", el cual ejecuta el siguiente codigo de JavaScript:

```
function consultaCAT() {                
        var credenciales64 = "amFyZXllczoxMTExMTE=";

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.open('POST', 'https://demoes20.softexpert.com/softexpert/webserviceproxy/se/ws/dc_ws.php', true);

        var strRequest =
            '<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:document">' +
            '<x:Header/>' +
            '<x:Body>' +
            '<urn:searchCategory></urn:searchCategory>' +
            '</x:Body>' +
            '</x:Envelope>';

        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + credenciales64);
        /*xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('sec-fetch-mode','cors');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('sec-fetch-site','cross-site');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('set-fetch-site','cross_site');*/

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                //Limpiar tabla
                var Table = document.getElementById("tbodyT")
                var tbRows = Table.getElementsByTagName('tr')
                var rowCount = tbRows.length
                for (var x = rowCount - 1; x > 0; x--) {
                    Table.removeChild(tbRows[x])
                }

                //Llenar Tabla
                var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML
                var h1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('CDCATEGORY')
                var h2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('CDCATEGORYOWNER')
                var h3 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('IDCATEGORY')
                var h4 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('NMCATEGORY')


                for (var i = 0; i < h1.length; i++) {
                    var CDCATEGORY = h1[i].firstChild.nodeValue
                    var CDCATEGORYOWNER = h2[i].firstChild.nodeValue
                    var IDCATEGORY = h3[i].firstChild.nodeValue
                    var NMCATEGORY = h4[i].firstChild.nodeValue

                    var ajaxurl = './php/metodos.php',
                        data = {
                            'action': 'conciliacionWS_BDD',
                            'IDCATEGORY': IDCATEGORY,
                            'NMCATEGORY': NMCATEGORY
                        };

                    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                        var texto = String(response)
                        var arrSplit = texto.split(/(?:##|&&)+/);

                        if (arrSplit[0] == "NO EXISTE") {
                            tabBody = document.getElementById("tbodyT");
                            row = document.createElement("tr");
                            cell1 = document.createElement("td");
                            cell2 = document.createElement("td");
                            textnode1 = document.createTextNode(arrSplit[1]);
                            textnode2 = document.createTextNode(arrSplit[2]);
                            cell1.appendChild(textnode1);
                            cell2.appendChild(textnode2);
                            row.appendChild(cell1);
                            row.appendChild(cell2);
                            tabBody.appendChild(row);
                        }
                    });
                }

            }

        };

        xmlhttp.send(strRequest);
    }
```

Dentro de este código de Javascript, inicialmente se llama el WebService y se obtiene un arreglo de datos y se lo almacena en xmlDoc.
El campo de estos datos que debo obtener para validar con la Base de datos se llama IDCATEGORY, y este es el que se toma para poder ser enviado a un código de PHP llamado metodos.php

La función a la que se accede en metodos.php es la siguiente:

```
//Conectividad con botones de index.html
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'crearTabla':
            $arr_se = $_POST['arr_se'];
            $arr_as = $_POST['arr_as'];
            $id_se = $_POST['id_se'];               
            crearTabla($arr_se, $arr_as, $id_se, $con);
            break;
        case 'conciliacionWS_BDD':
            $IDCATEGORY = $_POST['IDCATEGORY'];     
            $NMCATEGORY = $_POST['NMCATEGORY'];     
            conciliacionWS_BDD($IDCATEGORY, $NMCATEGORY, $con);
            break;
    }
}
function conciliacionWS_BDD($IDCATEGORY, $NMCATEGORY, $con){
    $sqlBuscar='SELECT id_se from "params"'. "where id_se='$IDCATEGORY';";
    $rs = pg_query( $con, $sqlBuscar);
    $obj = pg_fetch_array($rs);
    if(($obj['id_se']) == ""){
        echo "NO EXISTE"."##".$IDCATEGORY."&&".$NMCATEGORY;
    } 
    else{
        echo "SI EXISTE";
    }
}
```

Ignoren los demás parametros que recibe la función. 
Esta funcion hace un query a la BDD y si el id_category **NO EXISTE** se retorna un mensaje similar al codigo de javascript, el mismo que en base a esa respuesta, define si agregar o no agregar una fila a una tabla existente en el código HTML.

El problema que tengo, es que si ejecuto la aplicacion en node (localhost:4000), el index.html se ve bien, se ejecuta el servicio y se obtienen los datos iniciales mediante un llamado SOAP, pero cuando se quiere llamar a **metodos.php** y pasar los datos para la consulta con la BDD me sale un error que dice "CANOT POST /php/metodos.php

Les adjunto capturas para que vean el detalle.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: dc_ws.php es la ejecucion correcta del WebService]

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Un abrazo.

Comment: ¿Php y Node corren en el mismo servidor, usando el mismo puerto? Creo que por ahí puede estar el problema.

Comment: Es **imposible** que corran los 2 en el mismo puerto. El problema está ahí, ciertamente: te falta poner la URL correcta al archivo `.php`.